Non contact AC voltage detector circuit current calculation
This seems to be a common circuit for a non-contact AC voltage detector:

Non-Contact AC Line Detector using BC547
The probe generates a small amount of current when it is near an AC line due to capacitive coupling.

How is this current amplified in each stage mathematically?
What calculations are involved to find the current flowing through the LED and the buzzer?

The datasheets of BC547, battery, LED and the buzzer are attached below.

BC547: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/BC546.pdf
Battery: https://data.energizer.com/pdfs/522.pdf
LED: https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/YSL-R531R3C-A13.pdf
Buzzer: https://www.hydzelec.com/uploads/YHE12.pdf

I am using  model YHE12-05 buzzer. For the BC547, I am using the variant B with minimum hfe of 200.

With enough current gain, and 2 prior transistors apparently is enough for the purpose, just consider Q1 as saturated. So the source voltage is applied across the series chain of R1, LED1 and BZ1. A datasheet on the battery, the buzzer, and the LED would be needed to get a quantitative estimate.

Hello, thank you for the reply. I have added the datasheets of the components in the question.

When you are having difficulty understanding a circuit, simulate it.

@KailashKumaravel It appears that the buzzer and the LED and battery are compatible with respect to the desired current. That's good. Given the battery, you need two of them arranged in series for the circuit. Not one.

@periblepsis Do you mean I have to connect two batteries in series to get a total supply voltage of 18V?

@KailashKumaravel Hmm. Thanks for asking. I was looking at the -12 version. But reading better, I see you are using the -5 version of the buzzer, which is 4-7 V. The LED is 2-2.4 V. So 2 for the LED, 4 for the buzzer, and 4.4 for the resistor still adds up to more than 9 V. This means changing the resistor value, I think. So 2.2 for the LED, 5 for the buzzer, leaves 9-2.2-5=1.8 for the resistor. A 91 Ohm resistor or 100 Ohm resistor would be better then. Should be okay as the battery voltage declines a bit, as well. Thanks for bringing this up. My mistake!

related discussion: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/452680/non-contact-ac-voltage-detector-resistors

Realize that this circuit was most likely created by a hacker, not an Engineer. Its characteristics are highly dependent on the beta of the transistors. An ESD discharge to the input will most likely blow out Q3.
I assumed that the input is capacitively coupled. It may be more complicated than that.
The first simulations were odd, then I found that the base voltage was going very negative. With a real transistor it will breakdown, I simulated this with zeners. Another reason why this is a poor circuit, the poor input transistor will see large negative voltages. Apparently, the current is low enough to prevent damage.
Sorry, I didn't find a mathematical answer. But I wanted everyone to realize that the output will be a square wave. The LED won't care. The buzzer might care, I assume that they picked a buzzer that is tolerant of a square wave.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

